# Conditional formating in Excel 2010 with multiple criteria including dates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, formatting

I have two side by columns (C & D). In column C I have due dates, and in column D I have date completed.  I'd like to conditionally format the dates in column C to change color as indicated by the following criteria"

1. If the Completed date in "D" is less than, or equal to the Due date in "C" then fill green
2. If the Completed date in "D" is greater than the Due date in "C" then fill red
3. If the Completed date in "D" is blank, then no fill
4. If D is blank, and the Due date in "C" is coming up in the next week then fill yellow

I've been trying for two days to figure this out, and I have it close, but the yellow formatting doesn't seem to work if D is blank.

Comment: What do you mean by "...coming up in the next week?" Do you mean sometime between Sunday and Saturday of the following week, or within the next seven days?

Comment: Actually, I like sometime between Sunday and Saturday better.

Comment: FWIW, you would have to test for conditions 3 and 4 in reverse order, because in the order it's in, 3 will always be true before 4.

Comment: How do I handle the "and" part of condition 4?

Comment: It's in my answer for the yellow formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the appropriate range in column C.
 For the green formatting use this formula:

> =AND(D2<=C2,D2<>"")

For the red formatting use:

> =AND(C2"")

For the yellow use:

> =AND(WEEKNUM(TODAY())< WEEKNUM(C2),D2="")

and for the blank formatting use:

> =OR(D2="")

**Edit:** The formula for yellow will not work at the end of the year. You'd have to combine AND and OR if you can't live with that once-a-year fail. I'm fairly certain I could provide a formula that would work in that instance.[image: Example]